# jQuery tablesorter + resizing column widths

Tags: jquery, resize, tablesorter

Is there a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) plugin for resizing table columns that works with tablesorter?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) has everything you may want.

Comment: this thing needs absolute column widths, zero margins and who knows what else to work correctly (I have stopped digging).

Answer (score 6):

You should try the [colResizable](http://quocity.com/colresizable) plugin. It allows to resize columns manually, and it is tiny in size (2.8 KB) and does not require any other libraries or stylesheets.

Comment: this thing requires jquery older than 1.9 and does not seem to work with tables that are not visible when you call it.

Answer (score 3):

A very easy plugin for adding resizable columns is [SimpleResizableTable.js](http://robau.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/unobtrusive-table-column-resize-with-jquery-as-plugin/).

Comment: great plugin for simple resize

Comment: does not seem to work on multiple tables in selection, you need to give them ids and init one by one. also breaks on tables that aren't visible at init time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [jquery.kiketable.colsizable](http://www.ita.es/jquery/jquery.kiketable.colsizable.htm) would work for what you need.

Another one that looks good is [Ingrid, the jQuery Datagrid](http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/). It has more features and will sort your columns without the use of tablesorter.

Comment: kiketable thing does not seem to do anything at all... could it be that it needs colgroup thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a plugin for tablesorter, the [jQuery Grid Plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) (still in alpha) does resize columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the jQuery UI Resizable plugin to resize columns. The plugin can not directly resize TH elements, but even better COLGROUP > COL elements which makes the browser rendering very fast and enables proper HTML.

Some more evaluation, a live demo and complete code can be found in the blog post *[Resizable Table Columns with jQuery UI](http://ihofmann.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/resizable-table-columns-with-jquery-ui/)*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: this thing requires your table to have exact html/css or change js code.